# fclose() throws segfault in Docker container

Tags: c, docker, segmentation-fault

The following C program creates an empty file of a specified length.  I have tested this on my local Ubuntu 20.04 laptop and it works.  I am now running it in an instance at Digital Ocean (Ubuntu 22.04), but the line "fclose(outfile);" throws a segmentation fault.  In the cloud I am running it in a Docker container, but not locally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t create_empty_file (char * out_fname, size_t file_size)
{
    FILE *outfile;
    char buf[1024];

    outfile = fopen(out_fname, "wb+");

    if (outfile == NULL) {
        strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
        printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf); }

    fseek(outfile, file_size, SEEK_SET);

    if (errno != 0) {
        strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
        printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf); }

    fputc('\0', outfile);

    if (errno != 0) {
        strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
        printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf); }

    fclose( outfile );

    return 0;
}
```

The file does get created AND the file does get closed -- I know that because it shows a file size of zero until the file is closed, and the file does show its 4GB specified length.

In the usual case, fclose throws a segfault when the file pointer is null, but that's not the case here.  And it works on my local laptop.

Here are the segfault details from GDB:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fe121321c70 in __GI__IO_setb (f=f@entry=0x145b210, b=b@entry=0x0, eb=eb@entry=0x0, a=a@entry=0) at ./libio/genops.c:338
338     ./libio/genops.c: No such file or directory.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: I had never seen anyone testing if the file was open using `if (errno != 0) {`. It would be better to test `outfile == NULL`

Comment: 1) You're checking errno but still doing file operations on the file even if it's an error. 2) Read the docs. fopen returns NULL on error, only then should you check errno for (potentially) an error message (in some cases it doesn't). 3) use perror from string.h when testing, you don't need to worry about allocations. 4) strerror is statically allocated, there's no need to copy it to an intermediary buffer before printing it. 5) Error check all of your calls (fseek, etc). They can all fail, and it might be putting the descriptor into a bad state.

Comment: Does it behave differently if you do [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/n6bPTG95b)? It's still relying on Posix to create a sparse file, so extending the file like that won't work in all environments.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo - that links me to the Compiler Explorer Privacy Policy.  I'm not sure what you mean by "like this."  Thanks for your comment on Posix, but this is an Ubuntu 22.04 Docker image, so I would think POSIX would work the same way as all Ubuntu like my local 22.04 where it works.

Comment: Ok, you've never used Compiler Explorer? Sorry, that's so rare nowadays. What about this then: https://pastebin.com/0WCxEk5b

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo - yes, I use Compiler Explorer, but not often.  I was confused when I saw their policy screen.  I see the code you pasted my code in there, and I will try that, but with a modification because this is a shared object and has no "main" so I just rename main.  I'll post back when I've tested it.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. You may want to check the return from `fseek` too, like this: https://pastebin.com/9CL8kehB - if that doesn't help, check `fputc` too. Everything may fail :-)

Comment: Why not just use `ftruncate()`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo - it also segfaults at fclose().

Comment: @RTC222 Which one of the two `fclose`s segfaults? Did you add a check to see if `fputc` succeeds too?

Comment: The fclose at line 15 -- the second one.  fputc does succeed.

Comment: Also, as was the case with my earlier version, the file DOES get closed because the file size is 1.1GB; before closing the file it shows as 0 -- so I know it is closed.  Then the segfault.

Comment: @Shawn "Why not just use ftruncate()? –" --> `ftruncate()` is not part of the standard C library.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - don't I have to call fclose() after ftruncate()?  My problem is with fclose().

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So? OP's using Ubuntu.

Comment: @RTC222 You typically don't use `fopen()` at all with `ftruncate()`. `open()` a file descriptor instead.

Comment: @Shawn - I think you're on to a solution.  I will try it with open and ftruncate.  I don't need portability.

Comment: @Shawn So ..., You asked why "Why not just use ftruncate()? –" and if one wanted to make portable code, `ftrunctate()` is not an option regardless of the OS one uses.  YEt a late comment by OP indicates "don't need portability."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - why isn't ftruncate an option?  All I need is a file descriptor from the open system call.

Comment: @RTC222 "why isn't ftruncate an option?" --> Post was not tagged with an compiler nor OS nor doctor.  As such a generic solution was called for.  Yet since you seem to be fine with an implementation specific solution, using `ftruncate()`, `open()`, etc. which are not part of the standard C library, is an option.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - according to https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html open() is part of the C standard library.

Comment: @RTC222 According to the C spec, `open()` is not part of the standard C library.  Various implementations do add their non-standard things to what they call the standard C library, yet that does not make it standard.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - in this case it doesn't matter because I don't need portability.  There is good news, I rewrote it using open, ftruncate and close.  See my answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As others have pointed out, you should use ftruncate(2) if available, especially since fseek(3) won't work correctly if `file_size - 1` is larger than 0x7fffffff, which can easily happen in 64-bit programs. My answer addresses other issues with your code, and it assumes that `file_size` is small enough.)

You are not handling the errors correctly, and that may cause memory corruption, which breaks `fclose(...)`. Most likely the bug is in your program, not in `fclose(...)`.

Here is how to handle the errors correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Returns 0 on success, -1 on error. Sets errno to a useless value. */
int create_empty_file(char *out_fname, size_t file_size) {
    FILE *outfile = fopen(out_fname, "wb");
    if (outfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fopen: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (file_size != 0) {
        if (fseek(outfile, file_size - 1, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fopen: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            fclose(outfile);
            return -1;
        }
        fputc('\0', outfile);  /* Error checked below. */
        if (ferror(outfile) || fflush(outfile) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fputc\n");
            fclose(outfile);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

After changing your function to this, you won't get a segmentation fault. You may get an I/O error though (printed by `fprintf(stderr, ...)` above), pay attention to it. Maybe the reason for the I/O error is that your filesystem is full. (However, that's unusual in this case, creating a huge file by seeking shouldn't use much filesystem space, most filesystems optimize those holes away.)

Here are some useful rules of thumb for error checking:

- In general, check the return value of each function you call.
- Only use `errno` if the return value of the previous I/O function was not success.
- For stdio buffered output (e.g. `fputc(...)`), you may skip the error checking, and check the error after flushing explicitly (`if (ferror(outfile) || fflush(outfile) != 0)` in the code above).
- In general, stop I/O on a file (and close it) after the first error.
- Propagate the error indication in the return value of your function.
- Print the error the stderr.

I've fixed two more problems above:

- `+` is not needed in `fopen(..., "wb+")`, because you don't want to read from the file.
- You need `file_size - 1` for seeking, because `fputc` adds 1 more byte.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful post on correct error handling.  I solved this problem in another way - see my answer below.  But I chose yours as best answer because you addressed the original problem.  I used a workaround.  Your analysis should help me in the future.

Comment: Note that `fseek()` takes a `long int` as its second parameter, and if the file size is greater than `LONG_MAX` and/or `long int` is *smaller* than `size_t`, such as on 64-bit Windows systems, lots of other issues could occur.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Thank you, I've updated by answer to warn about this.

Comment: re: `fprintf(stderr, "fopen: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));`  You need to include the name used to attempt the fopen (eg `fprintf(stderr, "fopen: %s: %s\n", out_fname, strerror(errno));`, and there is really no point in including `errno` in the output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I kept it similar to the original function. Indeed, reporting the filename is useful, and reporting the numerical errno value is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion by Shawn above, to use ftruncate, I rewrote this using open, ftruncate and close, and it works perfectly.  Thanks for all replies to this question.  Here's the new code:

```
size_t create_empty_file (char * out_fname, off_t file_size, mode_t mode)
{
    
    char buf[1024];

    int fd = open(out_fname, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    
    if (fd == 0) {
        strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
        printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf); }
        
    ftruncate(fd, file_size);
    
    if (errno != 0) {
        strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
        printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf); }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is still incorrect and works by accident. Instead of `if (errno != 0)` (and the call above it), you should check `if (ftruncate(fd, file_size) != 0)`.

Comment: RTC222, Aside:, why copy the error message into `buf[]` instead of printing it with `printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); }`?

Comment: Please see my answer on how to do error checking, to avoid surprises.

Comment: Don't call ftruncate(2) if open(2) fails!

Comment: RTC222, as a helper function `create_empty_file()` should not rely on `errno` is 0 before the function call.  Better to check the return value of `ftruncate()`.

Comment: The correct way to check for errors after open(2) is `if (fd < 0)`. What you wrote is incorrect, and it works only by accident.

Comment: @pts, `if (fd < 0)`? As I read the man page, the test should be `if (fd == -1)`.

Comment: The difference between `if (fd < 0)` and `if (fd == -1)` doesn't matter, because `open` never returns other negative values. Pick whichever you like.